# Make a number display without decimals and rounding in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, format

I want to just enter a number for the amount of inventory we have. I do not want decimal places and I want to type in the number without it rounding.

For example when I type in `6`, it reads as `0.06` and rounds to `0`. I just want to see `6` in the cell and I want it to be a number.

Comment: Please try @barry houdini's [answer](http://superuser.com/a/516296/316320) and *mark it as answer* if it works for you. I just tried what he proposed and it **solved the weird behavior**.

Answer (score 2):

The cell you're typing in is probably formatted as a percentage, with one decimal place.
Right-click the cell, click "Format Cells", and open the Number tab. Select the "General" number type.

Note that if the number is solely for human reading, and you won't ever need to do calculations on it, the "Text" format is better, as it will accept the input *exactly* as written.

Comment: It is formatted as number with no decimal place. I can't use text as the cell will be part of a formula

Comment: That's fine then. The "General" type should be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: but when I type in 6, It registers 0.06 and rounds to 0

Comment: Thanks for the edit Jonathan, you obviously had the right Excel version at hand ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you enter `6` and it appears as `0.06` you have Excel set up to **automatically add decimal places**.

Change that like this depending on your Excel version:

### Excel 2010

- Click on *File* Menu at top left - select *Excel Options* then go to *Advanced* and under *Editing Options* **uncheck the *automatically insert a decimal point*** option.

### Excel 2007

- Click on *Office button* at top left - select *Excel Options* then go to *Advanced* and under *Editing Options* **uncheck the *automatically insert a decimal point*** option.

### Excel 2003

- In Excel 2003 and earlier versions you can access this option through *Tools* > *Options* > *Edit* > **uncheck *Fixed decimal Places***.

Once you have done that make sure your cells are formatted to `General` or `Number` (zero decimal places) and when you enter 6 you will see just 6.